# Rolling 30 indistinguishable dice all at once, such that every die has $6$ sides, How many different results can we get?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am still trying like to understand the question, so I took an example of rolling two dice together, each with $6$ sides, I can get $\{ 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 \} $ as results which is equal to $11$ different results. But I'm not really succeeding at understanding how can I generalize or if I really understood the question correctly.

I would appreciate any help or explanation, thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut that was a typo, I just fixed it. about the question im really just still new and its how i understood it, I was wondering if I got it correct or no

Comment: The result of what? It seems you mean the sum of values on each die, but at least state it. With a sum of $n$ dice, it's quite obvious that you must get a value between $n$ (all "1") and $6n$ (all "6"). It's about as obvious that you can get all values in between: start from all "6", decrement each die by one in turn, so you get all "5" at the end: all values between $5n$ and $6n$ appear. Continue decrementing until you get all "1".

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut that's the problem with me, that I don't know if I understood the question correctly, it said "how many different results we can get", and I was wondering what it means if it means sum or whatever. seems like I understood it wrong though according to the answer that I got.

Comment: Oh, so I don't expect that it means the sum. A result is a set of values of each die, or as Empy2 suggests, how many of each value.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Yes thanks for the help :), now it ticks with the stars and bars method or balls in bins, where I have 6 bins, and 30 balls, that are indistinguishable, so the answer would be (30+6-1 choose 30), can you approve? im still new to combinatorics :)

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the lowest possible total, and the highest total, and decide whether every sum in between is possible.
OTOH, the way I read the question was that an outcome might be 'three 1s, seven 2s, six 3s, four 4s, two 5s and eight 6s'.  That way needs 'stars and bars', which you can look up.

Comment: ahh this makes more sense now, it would have been how many different sums we can get for my example to work.